# C# Lambda expression performance when using instance variables

Tags: c#, lambda

I just red JetBrains article about boosting performance when using lambda expressions: [Unusual Ways of Boosting Up App Performance. Lambdas and LINQs](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/07/24/unusual-ways-of-boosting-up-app-performance-lambdas-and-linqs/).

I was wondering does using instance variable cause the same kind of decrease in performance?
In the article it was told that the next kind of code using a refenrence to a variable in the same method scope inside a lambda expression would slow performance:

```
public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<Something> myIEnumerable){
  DateTime yesterDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
  return myIEnumerable.Where(obj => obj.Expired>yesterDay);
}
```

But what if I access instance variables. Would it have the same negative kind of effect?:

```
class SomeClass{

  private DateTime _yesterDay;

  public void Foo(IEnumerable<SomeThing> myIEnumerable){
    _yesterDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    IEnumerable<SomeThing> someThings = DoSomeThing(myIEnumerable);
    //...
  }

  public IEnumerable<Something> DoSomething(IEnumerable<Something> myIEnumerable){
    return myIEnumerable.Where(obj => obj.Expired>_yesterDay);
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Want to know which horse is faster? [Then race your horses!](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: At least give an example that compiles.

Comment: Do you want to return the result into the void?

Comment: The 2nd example wouldn't create an inner class, like the 1st example. That's where you gain performance because it won't instantiate a new object every time you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

In the jetBrains article, they are right on fact that instanciating delegate on each call can cost and is required only when context is not constant.

Closure is required to capture instance (or local variable) and cannot be natively cached. If you use only delegate arguments, constants and static members, closure is not requiered.

In another hand, the cost can affect only a massively called code (hot path) like big batch or code made for foundation (architects concern).

In most of case, taking this overhead to change design seems to be a premature optimization that can really cost for maintaining.